# can i crop image by coordinates  like (10,10,320,312)?

Tags: iphone, ios, crop

Goal : How Crop a image after zooming. can i crop image after zooming at predefined coordinates like (10,10,320,312). my UIImageView has this size?

I have a `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView` and I can zoom my image. I wants after zooming when I press `cropButton` the image which is displaying in `UIImage` is cropped. I wants size of image equal to `UIImageView` size.

thanks !!

before zooming
[image: before zooming]       after zoom and crop   [image: after zoom and crop]

my code is here.

```
-(void)cropButtonClicked
{   
    //Calculate the required area from the scrollview
    CGRect visibleRect;
    float scale = 1.0f/scroll.zoomScale;
    visibleRect.origin.x = scroll.contentOffset.x * scale;
    visibleRect.origin.y = scroll.contentOffset.y * scale;
    visibleRect.size.width = scroll.bounds.size.width * scale;
    visibleRect.size.height = scroll.bounds.size.height * scale;

    UIImage *image = [self imageByCropping:imageView.image toRect:visibleRect];

    imageView.image=image;


}


- (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)myImage toRect:(CGRect)cropToArea{
CGImageRef cropImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(myImage.CGImage, cropToArea);
UIImage* cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropImageRef];

CGImageRelease(cropImageRef);
return cropped;
}
I use this logic.. Am I RIGHT? (May be i have to check my ScrollView programming)
```

Comment: What have you done to achieve goal ? Post some code what you did for that ?

Comment: @stackBlue. What you do is correct. What problem do you face?

Comment: @Vignesh it's crop image .but not which is seen in UIImageView . it cuts the upper portion which is not display in UIImageView

Answer (score 2):

May this code use full for you..!!

```
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);<br>
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, 0);<br>
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);<br>
[image drawInRect:imageRect];<br>
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();<br>
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```